# Add custom fields in Concur Rest API

Tags: rest, sap-concur

I am trying to invoke following concur REST service
https://www.concursolutions.com/api/v3.0/expense/allocations

How can I add custom fields into it. As per the doc, it supports 20 custom fields

Comment: are you looking to do a GET of existing allocations on create new ones? Also, have you seen the JavaScript SDK? https://github.com/concur/concur-platform-sdk-js

Comment: I was testing GET of existing allcoations.

Comment: When you make the GET call, you should automatically get all of the custom fields in the response. If you are not, can you share the output, and we can take a look...